# H2 database - CSVREAD - read timestamp from csv to a timestamp column

Tags: java, timestamp, h2

I am using H2 DB in my Java application. I want to load a .csv file to a table. My .csv file contains a timestamp in format `07/16/2011 02:43:43` but the default timestamp format of H2 DB is `2005-12-31 23:59:59`

so when I am using `CSVREAD` to load that .csv file to the DB, I am getting the following exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "07/16/2011 02:43:43"; SQL statement:
-- row #2 ('CIRCLE', 'MSISDN', 'PORT_IN_DATE', 'OPERATOR', 'PRODUCT_TYPE', 'PORT_ID') [22007-163]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
at org.h2.value.ValueTimestamp.parse(ValueTimestamp.java:87)
at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:819)
at org.h2.table.Column.convert(Column.java:155)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.addRow(Insert.java:153)
at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:524)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select convert(parseDateTime(DOB,'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss'),timestamp) as NEWNAME
from CSVREAD('file.csv')
```

where file.csv has a column labelled DOB

And to insert into your table:

```
insert into YOURTABLE 
    (
     select convert(parseDateTime(DOB,'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss'), timestamp)
     from CSVREAD('file.csv')
    )
```

Comment: +1 Would you like to look at another Q related to H2 DB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761690/h2-database-csvread-skip-loading-header-line-of-the-csv-file-into-db

Comment: and one more thing.. In `CSVWRITE` function, the query is enclosed by single quotes. So how can I write this where clause `start_timestamp > '2011-09-01 00:00:00.00'` as it contains single quote.

Comment: wouldn't an escape work? like start_timerstamp . \'2011-09-01 00:00:00.00\'?

Comment: double single quotes worked `start_timestamp > ''2011-09-01 00:00:00.00''`