# H2 database - CSVREAD - skip loading header line of the csv file into db

Tags: csv, h2

I am using H2 DB in my java application. I want to load a .csv file to the DB. This file contains column headers as the first line of the file. So while loading the file into the DB through `CSVREAD` command, H2 is trying to parse the first line also and thus failing.

So how to skip loading the first line. Below the query I am using to load the file to the DB:

```
"CREATE TABLE TEST (CIRCLE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50), MSISDN VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50), PORT_IN_DATE TIMESTAMP, OPERATOR VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255), PRODUCT_TYPE VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255), PORT_ID VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255)) AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('src/test/resources/test.csv', "
```

Comment: The statement in your question is truncated; could you add the missing part? Please also add newlines if possible so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [CSVREAD](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread) function supports both files with and without column header. If the file contains a column header, then don't supply the column list in the function, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('test.csv');
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('data/test.tsv', null, 'rowSeparator=' || CHAR(9));
```

and if the file doesn't contains the column header, then supply the column list in the function call, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('test2.csv', 'ID|NAME', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=|');
```

Comment: For `tsv` file `fieldSeparator` should be `char(9)` instead of `rowSeparator`, hence `SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('data/test.tsv', null, 'fieldSeparator=' || CHAR(9));` is correct for `tsv`.

Comment: What does the `|` mean in that fieldSeparator?